# How to get unique client ID in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, client-server

In my code 'main.js' I am trying to print socket ID of client. When I connect a client to my server 'main.js', The code does not print anything, either in the console or the browser.

Server side code(main.js):

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = 8000;
server.listen(port)

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send({name:ID});
});

var ID;
io.on('connection',function(socket){
        ID = socket.id;
        console.log('client id - '+ID);     
});
```

Comment: How did you get on with the below answer, Shiva?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a small error. Socket io server event is not `connections` (plural), but `connect / connection`. [See docs](https://socket.io/docs/).

Here is a working example:

**server.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = 8000;
server.listen(port)

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
  ID = socket.id;
  console.log('client id - '+ socket.id);     
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head></head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>    
    <script>  
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
        socket.on('connect', function(data) {
            console.log('socket connected')
         });
    </script>        
</body>
</html>
```

I can confirm that this is working both on server and client.